# How to test a helper method using Scala Test in Play framework

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, tdd, scalatest

I have a helper method that I use to validate the phone number using a regex.

```
object RegexValidator {

    //Does not match: (+447222)555555 | +44(7222)555555 | (0722) 5555555 #22
    def phoneNumber = text verifying pattern(getConf("regex.phoneNumber").r, error="")

}
```

This validation is used to validate the phone number in the controller:

```
val adminForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "phoneNo" -> phoneNumber
      )(AdministratorDetails.apply)(AdministratorDetails.unapply)
```

The validation is working fine. But, I want to write a Scala Test in my play application to validate the phoneNumber method. I would like to pass a number of test data also (something like parameterised tests).

Can someone help me with a sample code? I have looked into Scala Test documentation in Play Documentation but not able to get an idea to achieve this.

Comment: Where is `pattern` coming from?

Comment: `pattern` is coming from properties file and `getConf` is utility method to achieve this.

Comment: Did my response answer your question?

Comment: @LimbSoup Thank you for your response. But, I am quite new to Scala so finding it difficult to understand the syntax. Though I am reading scala, I am yet to reach a stage where I can understand your response. So, I am planning to read some more and visit your answer to understand it better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Read up on the `Either` type. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't quite tell what's in your scope to re-construct your example myself, I'm going to give an example of testing `Forms.nonEmptyText`, as your `def phoneNumber` ought to be returning `Mapping[String]` just as `nonEmptyText` is.

`Mapping[T]` has a `bind` function we can use in tests:

```
bind(data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], T]
```

It accepts a form mapping like `Map("email" -> "joe@example.com")`, and returns either errors, or the validated value wrapped in the `Either` type (which must be either `Left` or `Right`, with the common convention of using `Left` for errors and `Right` for success).

So I'm going to re-implement your function, just aliasing it for now to `nonEmptyText`:

```
def phoneNumber: Mapping[String] = Forms.nonEmptyText
```

Now let's try binding some form data:

```
phoneNumber.bind(Map("" -> "911"))
```

This evaluates to `Right("911")`, which is our success case. Now some bad data:

```
phoneNumber.bind(Map("" -> ""))
```

This evaluates to `Left(List(FormError("",error.required,WrappedArray())))`, indicating failure.

For the actual tests, you'll probably only care about the success or failure of the validation so we can base the assertions around the `Either` type:

```
phoneNumber.bind(Map("" -> "911")).isRight should be (true)
phoneNumber.bind(Map("" -> "")).isLeft should be (true)
```

I should note that outside of the `Form` mapping, the key associated with the `Mapping[String]` is an empty string, hence the empty strings for `Map` keys. From here you'd just need to swap out `phoneNumber` with your own implementation, and I trust you can make real test cases out of my samples.